# Questions with Prototype Cell and UITableView

Tags: uitableview

I have two kind of cell, one a standard title-subtitle cell, and another custom cell with two UITextField. And they have different identifier, VIEW and EDIT.

In my code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I need to create two kind of cell. At any time, I have only one cell in edit, so I create a `NSUInteger` to keep track of which cell is being edited.

My code looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell;
    if ( rowInEdit == indexPath.row )
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EDIT"];
        if ( !cell )
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
        }
        RLSite* site = [[RLSettings settings]siteAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel]setText:site.name];
        [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:site.url];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VIEW"];
        if ( !cell )
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"VIEW"];
        }
        RLSite* site = [[RLSettings settings]siteAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel]setText:site.name];
        [[cell detailTextLabel]setText:site.url];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Notice that my first part is definitely flawed. I don't know how to create a cell with prototype, and how to assign reuseIdentifier to it. Furthermore, I don't know how to access those `UITextField` in that cell once it's created.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e. `how to create a cell with prototype` you can follow these tutorials as I also learned it from one of these tutorials

Tutorials

1. [First one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) Which I referred.
2. [Second one](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_Build_Dynamic_TableViews_with_Prototype_Table_View_Cells)

And to excess the added text views you need to assign them tag values (obviously distinct).
Then use the below code to excess them in side your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
```

Here replace the `8` with your tag value :)